# Adjusting the range of a slider based on handle positions

Tags: reactjs, math, slider, scale, nouislider

I have a nouislider component with two handles. The handles represent start and end dates, using timestamps as values.
Everything works as expected. I would just like to add a feature where moving the handles will scale the slider by changing the range.

Here's what my slider looks like.
[image: My Slider]

I would like to have it so that, for instance, moving the left handle closer to the right will increase the lower range so that the area between the two handles is a greater percentage of the entire space. Kind of like a zooming effect.

I know how to update the range when I need to, I'm just wondering if there is some existing formula or general method of calculating such a thing, where the position of the handles will dictate the range; perhaps something using the distance between the left handle and the min range, and vice versa.

Comment: You want to scale the slider by the distance of handles on the very same slider? That sounds very unintuitive. Could you give an example of how you imagine that to look?

Comment: @NicoSchertler so take the slider shown in the question. Moving the left handle, representing 5/29/19, to the right to reach 6/1/19 would leave a very small space between the two handles. So after moving the handle I would change the lower range of the slider to be a value closer to 6/1/19. This would cause the left handle to move to the left, increasing the space between the two handles, as well as allowing more granularity in the movement of the handles. Moving the the handle to the left would have the opposite effect. I would ensure the range does not pass the min & max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to define the lower and upper bounds such that the handles will always be at fixed percentages of the total range. E.g.:

```
lh, rh := left handle and right handle values
lower, upper := lower and upper bounds of the range
tl, tr := percentages of left and right handles:
```

Then you want to solve the linear system

```
lh = (1 - tl) * lower + tl * upper
rh = (1 - tr) * lower + tr * upper
```

The solution of that is:

```
lower = (lh * tr - rh * tl) / (tr - tl)
upper = (rh - lh + lh * tr - rh * tl) / (tr - tl)
```

If you want to use `tl = 0.25` and `tr = 0.75`, you would get:

```
lower = 1.5 * lh - 0.5 * rh
upper = 1.5 * rh - 0.5 * lh
```

You can then clamp the range to your min and max values.